# JSTL formatDate always format the patten "MMM" to "Jan"

Tags: java, date, jsp, format, jstl

In a foreach loop, I set `curMonth` and `curDisplayedMonth` as follows:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${curDate}" type="date" pattern="m" var="curMonth" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${curDate}" type="date" pattern="MMM" var="curDisplayedMonth" />
```

and use them in the dropdown list as

```
<option value="<c:out value="${curMonth}"/>" <c:if test="${selectedMonth == curMonth}">selected</c:if>>
<c:out value="${curDisplayedMonth}"/>
</option>
```

but it formats all to Jan:

---

[image]

---

and the values in the options are correct:

---

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to correct your `pattern` option. For displaying the month with JSTL formatDate, use the following options:

```
<%-- Displays numeric month (ex: 1) --%>
<fmt:formatDate value="${curDate}" pattern="M" />

<%-- Displays  two-digit numeric month (ex: 01) --%>
<fmt:formatDate value="${curDate}" pattern="MM" />

<%-- Displays  the month abbreviation (ex: Jan) --%>
<fmt:formatDate value="${curDate}" pattern="MMM" />

<%-- Displays  the full month name (ex: January) --%>
<fmt:formatDate value="${curDate}" pattern="MMMM" />
```

Also, in your example above:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${curDate}" type="date" pattern="m" var="curMonth" />
```

`pattern="m"` represents the minute.

Answer (score 0):

The `type` and `pattern` attributes are mutually exclusive. You use one or the other, but not both.

The `type` attribute is just a convenient way to specify certain common patterns.

If you want to use `pattern`, you should remove the `type="date"` attributes.